# How to drop duplicates in dataframe ignoring punctuations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe -

```py
  print df

  Name | Role   |
  Mark | Admin  |
  Mark | Admin. |

  df = df.drop_duplicates()
  print df

  Name | Role  |
  Mark | Admin |
  Mark | Admin. |
```

I want to ignore any leading or preceding punctuations (full stop in this case) and drop duplicates.

Expected output -

```py
  df = df.drop_duplicates()
  print df

  Name | Role  |
  Mark | Admin |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) by all `punctuations` with space by all columns with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), get all duplicates by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import string
df = df[~df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(string.punctuation + ' ')).duplicated()]

print (df)
   Name    Role
0  Mark   Admin
```

Another idea is processing data with removed `punctuation`:

```
import string
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(string.punctuation + ' ')).drop_duplicates()

print (df1)
   Name   Role
0  Mark  Admin
```

**Detail**

```
#added list for see last space
print ([string.punctuation + ' '])
['!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ']
```

Comment: nice use of `string`, I think better than using regex

Comment: Can you please explain what does `string.punctuation + '  '` do?

Comment: @iCHAIT - Sure, it return all punctuation with space, because spce is not punctuation.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, also what if I want to do - `lambda x: x.str.strip(string.punctuation + ' ')` operation on a single column? Since i Have a date column which gives me an error - `Can only use .str accessor with string values!',`

Comment: @iCHAIT - Do you think `df['Role'] = df['Role'].str.strip(string.punctuation + ' ')` ?